# Parse: Cloud Code Variable Declartaion

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm not sure what's going wrong here / how I can fix it.

```
Parse.Cloud.job("expireTimes", function(request, response) {
var currentTime = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
var Wait = Parse.Object.extend("Wait");
Parse.Object.registerSubclass("Wait", Wait);
var query = new Parse.Query(Wait);
query.select(["times", "timestamp"]);
query.find({
    success: function(results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < timestamps.length; i++) {
            if (currentTime >= timestamps[i] + 60) {
                // Delete old wait times
                timestamps.splice(i, 1);
                times.splice(i, 1);
                i--;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        };
        response.success("Got " + results.length + " Query results: " + results[0].objectId);

    },
    error: function(error) {
        response.error("Request failed with response code");
        console.error("Request failed with response code ");
    }
});
});
```

It tell's me that timestamps is undefined:

```
I2015-11-27T17:00:03.419Z]Deployed v17 with triggers:
Jobs:
    expireTimes
E2015-11-27T17:01:04.489Z]v17 Ran job expireTimes with:
  Input: {}
  Result: ReferenceError: timestamps is not defined
    at e.query.find.success (main.js:9:24)
    at e.<anonymous> (Parse.js:14:28224)
    at e.s (Parse.js:14:27156)
    at e.n.value (Parse.js:14:26575)
    at e.s (Parse.js:14:27284)
    at e.n.value (Parse.js:14:26575)
    at e.s (Parse.js:14:27284)
    at e.n.value (Parse.js:14:26575)
    at e.<anonymous> (Parse.js:14:27228)
    at e.s (Parse.js:14:27156)
```

Not sure what this means /  how to fix it. I would assume declare timestamps, but I thought that was already done with the retrieval of the arrays in the columns "times" and "timestamp"

Any help would be much appreciated. **Thank you**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such idea as `query.select()`.  The only defined variables within the completion function are results (the array of retrieved parse objects) and currentTime, which you define in the enclosing scope.

The `registerSubclass` isn't useful unless you're actually defining a subclass.

As a starting exercise, try querying the class and logging the results.  The query can be as simple as:

```
var query = new Parse.Query("Wait");
query.find().then(function(results) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
    var firstId = (results.length>0)? results[0].id : "n/a";  // notice "id", not "objectId"
    console.log("Got " + results.length + " First id: " + firstId);
    response.success(results);
}, function(error) {
    response.error(error);  // return the real error so we can look at it
});
```

If `timestamp` is a defined attribute on your Wait class, you can get it with get()...

```
// just like before where you got the id, try "getting" an attribute
var firstTimestamp = (results.length>0)? results[0].get("timestamp") : "n/a";
// remember, this depends on you defining a "timestamp" attribute on the class
```

Comment: Both `timestamp` and `times` are arrays. `times` takes the user's time that they have submitted and `timestamp` just simply takes the time the user submitted it and puts it into an Int. That way, I can see if the `timestamp + 3600 < currentTime` and if it is, I delete it. So how do I grab those array's and run my for loop?

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful, but remember that all parse objects provide createdAt and updatedAt, and that queries can compare these with equality (but usually better) inequality, like `query.lessThan("updatedAt", someDate)`, where someDate is a JS date object.

Comment: Also note that array properties can be gotten with get() and their contents looped like any JS array.

Comment: Perfect. So now that I have changed my code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33964017/parse-update-object-from-cloud-code), how do I get it to actually delete and update the arrays in the object?

Comment: Got it.  I'll answer there.  One quick question, though, do you really want to do this to only one Wait object -- the first one found, `results[0]`?  Or do you want to change all of the Wait objects found?

Comment: Well the way I have it set up is that Wait is the overall class, and within that it has the properties of `name as String`, `times as Array`, `timestamp as Array`, `latitude as String`, and `longitude as String`. The application stores the times to a specific latitude and longitude and then averages them out. So I guess to answer your question, I want it to delete all instances within `Wait` that are older than an hour as they become inaccurate.